# How to write command line argument input redirection within a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, ffmpeg

I'm putting together a bash script to run movie rendering jobs. `ffmpeg` expects a multi-line text file as one of the arguments for concatenation filter to [join several files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) into one. Like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

There's also an option to write it all in a single line like so:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" A.mp4 B.mp4) -c copy Output.mp4
```

How do I write the latter for into a bash script, substituting the file names from other variables? Tryed splitting the variables, but its not the one that works. `$A` and `$B` variables contains paths to input files.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
TMP_LIST=$(printf "file '%s'\n" ${A} ${B})
APPEND="${FFMPEG} -f concat -i <<< {${TMP_LIST}} -c copy ${OUTPUT}"
# run the concatenation:
$APPEND
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to have a list and store the command in a variable (array) before it gets executed. Unfortunately process substitutions can only be kept alive by passing them as arguments to a function, so we have to use a function here:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST_IN_ARRAYS=("$A" "$B")  ## You can add more values.

function append {
    local APPEND=("$FFMPEG" -f concat -i "$1" -c copy "$2")  ## Store the command in an array.
    "${APPEND[@]}"  ## This will run the command.
}

append <(printf "file '%s'\n" "${LIST_IN_ARRAYS[@]}") "$OUTPUT"
```

Although I would have done it this way to make things simpler:

```
function append {
    "$FFMPEG" -f concat -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" "${@:2}") -c copy "$1"
}

append "$OUTPUT" "${LIST_IN_ARRAYS[@]}"  ## Or
append "$OUTPUT" "$A" "$B"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" "$A" "$B") -c copy Output.mp4
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.
Is there a way to put the whole command into a variable to execute then by just calling that variable? — asking for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: @SergikS: Use a function, variables are parsed in an way that makes this sort of thing difficult. See [BashFAQ #50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)